# I live in europe and can i use american wall charger for my iphone?

Tags: iphone, charger

I live in Europe and can I use american wall charger for my Iphone ?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere on the charger it will say acceptable input voltage.  US uses 110v, Europe 220v.  If the charger says it can accept 110-220v, then yes, you can use a plug adapter to plug the charger into the wall socket and charge your phone.

Comment: This is very pedantic but, European voltages are nominally 230 not 220.

Answer (score 0):

All original Apple iPhone power adapters should be compatible voltage wise to be used anywhere in Europe as they're rated for 100-240VAC 50/60Hz.